# Best way to fit window sealant?

Tags: windows, waterproofing

What tool can I use to cut a housing grove for this window sealant?

I've tried with my table saw,  but the kerf is 3mm, so I'd need to pack and glue it.

The push fit section, measured with calapers = 1.8 mm tight fit.

Would a router cut, or thinner kerf blade be better?

[image]

Comment: It seems like you've already got your answer. Your standard kerf blade makes too wide a kerf, so either get a thin-kerf blade that will be narrow enough, or use a router or other tool that will cut a slot that is no wider than you need to install it. If the installation instructions say it needs a 1.8mm slot to install it, that seems to be the right way to go.

Comment: Imagine that there are router bits that thin, but I have not seen them.  Know that saw blades do come in different sizes, think something like a finishing blade is much thinner, made for fine cuts.

Comment: Thanks both.  I've never used a router,  so wasn't sure if a)  I could get a bit small enough,  or b)  how good the cut would be. I'll look into thin blades.